# Is there an odeint equivalent for solve_ivp's event parameter?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, numerical-integration, odeint

I am currently using solve_ivp to solve a system of ODEs. I am hoping to switch to ODEint due to the decreased simulation time, however, I have not found an easy way to track events occurring using ODEint.

Is there a way to track events in ODEint and also to stop integration (like solve_ivp's terminal function) if a stopping condition is reached?

Comment: You can use the `method="LSODA"` parameter in `solve_ivp`. However, quite recently there were problems with the "dense output" interpolation (something about mixing maximal and current degree), which is used to find roots, so you would have to check bug reports and changelogs. While `ODEPACK` has a method that also finds roots, this is not used in scipy.

Comment: Hi Lutz, are you saying that using LSODA in solve_ivp will give an approximately equal runtime to ODEint? Also, I can set dense output to False no problem I dont have a requirement for this to be True. In addition, does ODEint have an equivalent to solve_ivp's "events" parameter?

Comment: The dense output is used internally for events, independent of the parameter. The solver checks for sign changes in the event functions and uses Brent on the interpolated solution to find a more exact location of the event. As far as I remember, the "LSODA" method uses the same methods and heuristics that are also used in "lsoda" of ODEpack, but it is implemented in python or closer to python, so might be slower in return for more flexibility.